# Windows MDM enrolment - Changing CN from UTF8 to PRINTABLE_STRING

Tags: utf-8, bouncycastle

Im implementing windows 8.1 MDM and using Bouncycastle for WSTEP stage of the device enrolment part. For this I need to override the CommonName of the signed certificate from 'UTF8' encoding to 'PRINTABLE_STRING' encoding.

By default BouncyCastle provides UTF8, is there a way to change this ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question : 
When i used, 
`new X500Principal("CN=someCN")` instead of `X500Name` object while creating `X509v3CertificateBuilder`, the created certificate's Common Name was in PRINTABLE_STRING encoding. Sample code looks like below,

```
X509v3CertificateBuilder certificateBuilder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(caCert,BigInteger.valueOf(new SecureRandom().nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3),new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 300)), new X500Principal("CN=someCN"), jcaRequest.getPublicKey());
```